# What's the precedence of method calls with and without parentheses?

Tags: ruby, methods, operator-precedence

## Previous answers

The [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7722757/6419007) to a similar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7722369/whats-the-precedence-of-rubys-method-call) is wrong.

Method calls are mentionned neither in Ruby [documentation](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.1/doc/syntax/precedence_rdoc.html) nor in the [community wiki](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21060234/ruby-operator-precedence-table).

## Method call without parentheses

#### Higher than `or`

`or` seems to have a lower precedence than a method call without parentheses :

```
puts false or true
```

is equivalent to

```
( puts false ) or true
```

and displays `false`.

NOTE: I know `or` shouldn't be used. Still, it's a good example to show that some operators do have lower precedence than method calls.

#### Lower than `||`

```
puts false || true
```

is equivalent to

```
puts (false || true)
```

and displays `true`.

## Method call with parentheses

The parentheses used for method call [don't seem](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37615125/6419007) to be grouping :

```
puts(false or true)
# SyntaxError: unexpected keyword_or
puts((false or true))
#=> true
```

## Question

Where should method calls with and without parentheses be in this precedence [table](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.1/doc/syntax/precedence_rdoc.html)?

## Bounty clarification

I'm looking for the exact location of method calls in the table. Preferably with examples proving it's lower than the previous one and higher than the next one.

The current answers also don't seem to mention method calls with parentheses.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: `puts(false or true) # => SyntaxError` wtf?

Comment: The "wordy" logical operators are a bit pathological. You'd need to do `puts((false or true))` to give a valid expression to the `puts` method.

Comment: @ndn wtf indeed! :) I was really surprised by that one. `puts(false or true)` is parsed as `{puts(false} or true)`

Comment: Why did you open a bounty on this? Didn't akuhn answer the question? If it's the `SyntaxError` thingy, it would have been more appropriate to open a new question.

Comment: Congratz on the Ruby gold btw ^^

Comment: Thanks. I updated the question. I should have written a better description in the bounty, sorry about that.

Comment: I see you're not far away of Ruby gold yourself. keep up the good work (preferrably with another avatar ;) )

Comment: @EricDuminil How did you end up with `{puts(false} or true)`?

Try `ruby -y -e "puts(false or true)"`

Comment: @bliof: It's just a way to show how Ruby tries to parse `puts(false or true)`, and why it fails. The equivalent isn't correct Ruby either. Does this [thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37613287/why-does-putsnil-or-4-fail-in-ruby/37615125#37615125) answer your question?

Comment: ¯\_(ツ)_/¯ https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/v2_4_0/parse.y#L1413 tl&dr; `keyword_or` needs a valid expresion on the left and on the right and on the left it is `puts(false` which does not have a closing bracket.

Comment: @bliof I think we agree on this one.`{puts(false}` was a (weird) way to write what you just commented.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

### Prelude

This aims to test all possible scenarios.

**Note** that when saying *"operator `X` has higher precedence than method invocation"* what is meant is in arguments. Aka:

```
invocation foo X bar
```

as opposed to (call on object)

```
X invocation
```

As far as the second case is concerned, method calls always have higher precedence.

---

### Short answer

It doesn't fit:

- It causes `SyntaxError` in some cases
- It has higher precedence than `rescue`, but lower than assignment

---

### Summary

- `not` can't be used after method invocation regardless of brackets
- Using brackets (`()`) with method invocations sometimes causes a `SyntaxError`. These cases are: `and`, `or`, `if`, `unless`, `until`, `while` and `rescue`
- In cases when brackets don't cause an error, they don't change the precedence in any way
- All operators, except for `and`, `or`, postfix `if`, `unless`, `until`, `while`, `rescue` have higher precedence than method invocation

---

Lets try it:

```
class Noone < BasicObject
  undef_method :!

  def initialize(order)
    @order = order
  end

  def method_missing(name, *args)
    @order << name
    self
  end
end
```

---

First unary:

```
# + and - will become binary
unary_operators = %i(! ~ not defined?)

puts 'No brackets'
unary_operators.each do |operator|
  puts operator

  order = []
  foo = Noone.new order
  bar = Noone.new order
  begin
    eval("foo.meta #{operator} bar")
  rescue SyntaxError => e
    puts e
  end
  p order
  puts '-----------'
end

puts 'Brackets'
unary_operators.each do |operator|
  puts operator

  order = []
  foo = Noone.new order
  bar = Noone.new order
  begin
    eval("foo.meta(#{operator} bar)")
  rescue SyntaxError => e
    puts e
  end
  p order
  puts '-----------'
end
```

Points taken:

- `not` after a method invocation is a `SyntaxError`
- all unary operators have higher precedence than method invocation regardless of brackets

---

Now binary:

```
binary_operators = %i(
  **
  * / %
  + -
  << >>
  &
  | ^
  > >= < <=
  <=> == === =~
  .. ...
  or and
)

puts 'No brackets'
binary_operators.each do |operator|
  order = []
  foo = Noone.new order
  bar = Noone.new order
  baz = Noone.new order
  begin
    eval("foo.meta bar #{operator} baz")
  rescue SyntaxError => e
    puts e
  end
  p order
end

puts 'Brackets'
binary_operators.each do |operator|
  order = []
  foo = Noone.new order
  bar = Noone.new order
  baz = Noone.new order
  begin
    eval("foo.meta( bar #{operator} baz)")
  rescue SyntaxError => e
    puts e
  end
  p order
end
```

Points taken:

- brackets around method invocation with `and` or `or` is a `SyntaxError`
- we have to test `and` and `or` further without brackets
- `..` and `...` call `<=>`. We have to test this further
- we couldn't test a few other binary operators this way, namely `&&`, `||`, `==`, `!=`, modifier `rescue`, `if`, `unless`, `until`, `while`
- other than the above mentioned, operators have higher precedence, regardless of brackets

---

```
def yes
  puts 'yes'
  true
end

def no
  puts 'no'
  false
end

def anything(arg)
  puts 'Anything'
  arg
end

anything yes and no
anything no or yes
anything yes && no
anything no || yes
anything(yes && no)
anything(no || yes)

anything yes == no
anything(yes == no)
anything yes != no
anything(yes != no)
```

Points taken:

- `and` and `or` have lower precedence without brackets
- `&&`, `||`, `==` and `!=` have higher precedence regardless of brackets

---

```
def five(*args)
  p args
  5
end

five 2..7
five(2..7)
five 2...7
five(2...7)
```

Points taken:

- `..` and `...` have higher precedence regardless of brackets

---

```
anything yes if no
anything(yes if no)
anything no unless yes
anything(no unless yes)

anything no until yes
anything(no until yes)
anything yes while no
anything(yes while no)
```

Points taken:

- brackets with `if`, `unless`, `until`, `while` cause a `SyntaxError`
- all of the above have lower precedence than method invocation without brackets

---

```
def error
  puts 'Error'
  raise
end

anything error rescue yes
anything(error rescue yes)
```

Points taken:

- brackets around `rescue` cause a `SyntaxError`
- `rescue` has lower precedence if no brackets are present

---

Ternary:

```
anything yes ? no : 42
anything(yes ? no : 42)
```

Points taken:

- ternary has higher precedence regardless of brackets

---

Assignment (left for last as it changes `yes` and `no`):

```
anything yes = no
anything(no = five(42))
```

Points taken:

- Assignment has higher precedence than invocation

Note that `+=` and the like are just shortcuts for `+` and `=` so they exhibit the same behaviour.

Comment: Very impressive, thanks. I really like the innovative way to check the precedence with `eval` and `order`. I never thought that it would make sense (or be possible at all) to rescue a `SyntaxError`. Note that `not` can be used as argument : `foo.meta((not bar))`

Comment: @EricDuminil, well not in that sense. But I agree that I did speak in absolutes which can be misinterpreted. Brackets in this answer refer to the brackets of method invocations and do not include ones used for grouping.

Comment: Does it mean that precedence cannot be defined as as [partial order](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partially_ordered_set) for the `operators + method call` set because it isn't transitive and isn't even defined for every pair? In that case, it would explain why [total order](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Total_order) cannot be achieved and why the table doesn't include method calls.

Comment: @EricDuminil, generally speaking, you can define order over incomparable set - any permutation would do (even if it will be absolutely impractical for language documentation to do). But it is indeed the case that if you add method calls (as understood in this context), the comparison is no longer transitive. Hence there is no total order.

Comment: Great job. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

In Ruby, method call precedence seems to be lower than `defined?` but higher than `or`.

For example:

```
puts defined? true
#=> true

puts false or true
#=> prints `false` and returns `true`
```

Note:
`puts(not true)` and `puts(false or true)` raise syntax errors.

Comment: `or` is lower than `defined?`. Do you mean lower than `defined?` and higher than `or`?. It seems to be true. method calls without parens seem to be between `defined?` and `not`.

Comment: You are right, I mixed them when writing the answer. I already edited it.

Answer (score 2):

Updating to actually answer the question.

Officially methods don't have a precedence. However as you demonstrate we can sort them into the precedence list and they fall between what we could consider "operators" and what we could consider "control flow" keywords.

See, https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/doc/syntax/precedence_rdoc.html

Which starts with operators, and ends with control-flow constructs like

```
?, :
modifier-rescue
=, +=, -=, etc.
defined?
not
or, and
modifier-if, modifier-unless, modifier-while, modifier-until
```

The only oddball there is `defined?` of which I don't understand why it hasn't been defined as a global function on the `Kernel` module anyway.

Missing `raise`, `loop`, `catch/throw` and others?

They are not keywords but method calls that are defined as `module_function` on the `Kernel` module. And since this module is included in `Object` they are made into private methods of all classes and thus appear to be global functions that are available everywhere.

Hope that helps to answer the question. Sorry for the original copypasta.

Comment: Uh oh, you're right. Copypasta mistake. Let me update this one here …

Comment: Thanks a lot. "Officially methods don't have a precedence". Do you know why? Can they be added into the table you link to, or do the precedence depends on other factors?

Comment: I don't know, maybe just an omission?

Comment: @akuhn, `defined?` isn't a method as it works with code rather than string or something else. If it was a method and you used something like `defined? x`, this will actually evaluate `x` before passing it to the method. You might work around this if you use a string `defined? 'x'`, but then are you referring to the local variable `x` or the string `'x'`? You can add special notation for one or the other and it gets complex.

Comment: This answer goes in the right direction. It doesn't pinpoint the exact location of where method call would be in the precedence table, though. Both with and without parens, pretty please :)